# If a text string contains something then return something in R

Tags: r

consider I have a `df` :

```
Product                                   Category   
Bill Payment for Torrent Power Limited    
Recharge of Videocon d2h DTH              
Bill Payment of Airtel Mobile
Recharge of Idea Mobile
```

Now if a string contains "Bill Payment" and "Mobile" both then i want to tag its category as "Postpaid" and if a string contains "Recharge" and "Mobile" i want to tag it as "Prepaid".

I am a beginner in R so an easiest way would be appreciated .

Result should be

```
Product                                   Category   
Bill Payment for Torrent Power Limited    NA
Recharge of Videocon d2h DTH              NA
Bill Payment of Airtel Mobile             Postpaid
Recharge of Idea Mobile                   Prepaid
```

Comment: df$Category[grepl("Bill\\sPayment") & grepl("Mobile")] <- "Postpaid"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `grep` to find the index of 'Product' with both 'Bill Payment/Mobile' ('i1') or 'Recharge/Mobile' ('i2').  After initializing the 'Category' as NA, we replace the elements based on the index i1 and i2.

```
i1 <- grepl('Bill Payment', df1$Product) & grepl('Mobile', df1$Product)
i2 <- grepl('Recharge', df1$Product) & grepl('Mobile', df1$Product)
df1$Category <- NA
df1$Category[i1] <- 'Postpaid'
df1$Category[i2] <- 'Prepaid'
df1
#[1] NA         NA         "Postpaid" "Prepaid"
```

Or a slightly more compact (that works with the example) option is

```
i1 <- grepl('.*Bill Payment.*Mobile.*', df1$Product)
i2 <- grepl('.*Recharge.*Mobile.*', df1$Product)
```

and do with `ifelse`

Answer (score 5):

A different approach is creating a numerical index first and then adding the respective values:

```
indx <- (grepl('Bill Payment', df1$Product) & grepl('Mobile', df1$Product)) + 
  (grepl('Recharge', df1$Product) & grepl('Mobile', df1$Product))*2 + 1L

df1$category <- c(NA, "Postpaid", "Prepaid")[indx]
```

which gives:

```
> df1
                                 Product category
1 Bill Payment for Torrent Power Limited     <NA>
2           Recharge of Videocon d2h DTH     <NA>
3          Bill Payment of Airtel Mobile Postpaid
4                Recharge of Idea Mobile  Prepaid
```

You can also create this index using the more compact notation as proposed by @akrun:

```
indx <- grepl('.*Bill Payment.*Mobile.*', df1$Product) + 
  grepl('.*Recharge.*Mobile.*', df1$Product)*2 + 1L
```

Or like @nicola proposed:

```
tmp <- grepl('Mobile', df1$Product)
indx <- (grepl('Bill Payment', df1$Product) & tmp) + (grepl('Recharge', df1$Product) & tmp)*2 + 1L
```

Comment: Was about to post along these lines, but I guess you should store `grepl('Mobile', df1$Product)` first to not repeat twice the same operation.

Comment: @nicola I think that is not possible because the cases where there is a match for the other two phrases but no match for `Mobile` should be excluded

Comment: I was saying something like `tmp<-grepl('Mobile', df1$Product)` and then `(grepl('Bill Payment', df1$Product) & tmp)+ ...`. Guess I explained it badly.

Comment: @nicola aha, now I see what you mean (I interpreted differently at first); added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
files=c('sssssssdddd', 'ggggggg', 'geabc', 'abcge')

to_vec(
    for(i in files) if (str_detect(i, 'ge') ) i
    )
```

Will return:

```
'geabc''abcge'
```